# IE 8 error on page when click on link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie8-browser-mode

I am working on windows server 2003 with IE 8

My website is working good on firefox and google chrome.

it also works good on IE, just one think,

there is a link that when I click, I `got error on page` yello at the bottom left of the page and nothing change on my website, I mean just that message appears and the webiste content is still the same.

#### note

I can run java script scrips on my IE right now .

the link exists here

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="LoadDetails('<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>','<%#Eval("Telephone")%>',this)">View Details</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

and the java script code, which is using is here:

```
function LoadDetails(memberID, mediaValue, el) {
  alert("asdfasdf")
    var listview1ToHide = document.getElementById('ListView1');
        listview1ToHide.style.display = 'none';

    if (!$(el).hasClass('disabledLink')) {
        $('#copyPhoneBtn').css('display', 'none');
        $('.disabledLink').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('disabledLink');
        });
        $(el).addClass('disabledLink');

        $('#subView').load('SubView.aspx?CustomerId=' + memberID + "&MediaValue=" + mediaValue + "&rand=" + Math.random());


        $("#newButtonContainer").css("height", "300px");
    } else {
        //alert('disabled..');


    }

}
```

Note, I am using asp.net

Note:the alert is working

Comment: If you double click the warning what message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click the warning message to see what it says, and you should be able to find where the error is